# How to place all auto-save files in a directory

Tags: init-file, auto-save

I would like to put all of my auto-save files into a directory, say something like

```
~/.emacs-saves
```

Based on what's written in the wiki, I came up with this:

```el
(setq backup-by-copying t      ; don't clobber symlinks
      backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs-saves"))    ; don't litter my fs tree
      delete-old-versions t
      kept-new-versions 6
      kept-old-versions 2
      version-control t)       ; use versioned backups
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" "~/.emacs-saves" t)))
```

Now my autosaves are going in my home directory, which is actually kind of an improvement, but not what I want.

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong, and how to correct it?  I'm also very interested in what this syntax means (It's an example from the wiki entry):

```el
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
```

What's with the comma in `,temporary-file-directory`?

Answer (score 16):

Put a slash at the end of your string. It's a directory.

```
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
  `((".*" "~/.emacs-saves/" t)))
```

The comma is used in the backquote notation.

```
(setq x 123)
(setq y `(my-x ,x))
(setq z (list 'my-x x)) ;; same as y
```

Comment: `auto-save-file-name-transforms` doesn't even need to be set to put all the backups into one directory.  Only `backup-directory-alist` is needed.

Comment: regarding the above comment - this question is asking about auto-save files and not backup files.

Comment: ahh that slash at the end fixed it for me! That has been bugging me for too long

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and now I use:

```
(let ((my-auto-save-dir (locate-user-emacs-file "auto-save")))
  (setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
        `((".*" ,(expand-file-name "\\2" my-auto-save-dir) t)))
  (unless (file-exists-p my-auto-save-dir)
    (make-directory my-auto-save-dir)))
(setq auto-save-default t
      auto-save-timeout 10
      auto-save-interval 200)
```

I don't now what `"\\2"` exactly does (maybe someone will explain) but it works correct, found it at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302973/emacs-auto-save-why-are-files-not-stored-in-the-correct-folder).
You can also replace `setq` part of the above example by:

```
  (setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
        `((".*" ,(file-name-as-directory my-auto-save-dir) t))))
```

Comment: According to documentation, `locate-user-emacs-file` creates the directory if it doesn't exist, so the `unless`-section shouldn't be needed. The documentation seems to be lying though, according to my tests.

Comment: And `"\\2"` is a back reference to the second matching group of the regex in the first element of auto-save-file-name-transforms (`".*"` in your code). There is no second matching group, so I think this works as expected by random chance. I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You need only the backup dir set correctly:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs-saves")))
```

I don't have any trailing / either. Also as erikstokes mentioned above, you don't need `auto-save-file-name-transforms` for backups to work.

Comment: `backup-directory-alist` is needed to put backups into one directory, `auto-save-file-name-transforms` is needed to put autosaves into one directory. Not clear if the OP wants both.

Comment: This question is asking about auto-save files and not backup files.