# How to set auto-save and backup path as subdirectory sibling of a given open file?

Tags: auto-save, backup

I am aware of [How to place all auto-save files in a directory](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17210/how-to-place-all-auto-save-files-in-a-directory), but I cannot figure it out from Emacs manual how to save all `auto-save` versions and all `backup` copies of a given file in a subdirectory sitting in *same parent directory* where the file resides?

For example, if I am editing file `etiology-macro.lisp`, I would need to keep all auto-save and backup versions of that file in subdirectory `auto-save-and-backup-subdirectory`

```
path/to/directory/
          etiology-macro.lisp
          auto-save-and-backup-subdirectory/
              etiology-macro.lisp.20170827-132731
              etiology-macro.lisp.20170827-133007
              etc.
```

How to set auto-save and backup path as subdirectory sibling of a given open file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will configure things to save both backup and auto-save files to an emacs-backups directory relative to the file you are visiting.

```
(let ((dir "emacs-backups"))
  (setq auto-save-file-name-transforms `(("\\([^/]*/\\)*\\([^/]*\\)\\'" ,(concat dir "/\\2")))
        backup-directory-alist `((".*" . ,dir))))
```

Note that for backup files you can just specify a directory (absolute or relative). For auto-save files you specify a transformation using a regex against the full path of the buffer file. In the above example I'm capturing the file name (without the parent dirs) and then referencing that in the replacement regex (`\2`) to append it to the relative directory.

Comment: Sorry for noticing this only now, I though sx was sending email upon new answers. Would it be possible to add the date timestamp, like in original question, ie, `etiology-macro.lisp.20170827-133007`? Thank you very much.

Comment: Autosave files are temporary (they get cleaned up when you actually save the file) so I'm not sure a timestamped naming strategy makes sense for those? But it does seem potentially useful for backups: in that case you would want to configure how many backups are kept (see variables `kept-old-versions` and `kept-new-versions`, as well as the `delete-old-versions` option.) For backup file names I think you would need to write a function to implement your naming strategy, and set `make-backup-file-name-function` to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer and information on autosave files. I will try to implement `make-backup-file-name-function` and report back.

Answer (score 0):

[backup-each-save.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/backup-each-save.el) script at EmacsWiki is the closest answer I could find for now.

From the inline comment:

```
;; This package copies every file you save
;; in Emacs to a backup directory tree (which mirrors the tree
;; structure of the filesystem), with a timestamp suffix to make
;; multiple saves of the same file unique.
```

I am still looking for a way to set auto-save and backup path as subdirectory sibling of a given open file.